# Hilbert scheme of quasi-projective sub-schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Fix a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, say over the complex numbers. I look for references about the moduli space of quasi-projective sub-schemes of $\mathbb{P}^n$. In the title I spoke about Hilbert scheme, even if I do not know if this terminolagy is appropriate.

I would like to know if this moduli space is a scheme, and if it has any decent property, such as separatedness. I do not expect it to be projective.

I do not know if in this case there is a sensible choice of numerical invariants, such as the Hilbert polynomial. Maybe the one could fix the Hilbert polynomial of the closure.

Comment: If you restrict yourself only to open subschemes, the observation that $D(f) = D(f^n)$ might make it difficult to parametrise them algebraically. Maybe this is a good first case to start with?

Comment: If you fix the Hilbert polynomial of the closure and of the boundary, then you can consider the flagged Hilbert scheme (parameterizing pairs $Z_b \subset Z_c \subset P^n$ of closed subschemes), and consider the family of differences $Z_c \setminus Z_b$.

Comment: A better first case to consider is flat families of (not necessarily closed) locally closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^1$ of dimension zero.  You should see immediately just how (massively) non-separated any such parameter space must be.

Comment: @Sasha: a potential problem with your suggestion is that there are many possible scheme structures on $|Z_b|$, all of which give the same locally closed subscheme $Z_c \setminus Z_b$.